# How to connect persistence.xml file with hibernate.properties

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to declare most of my persistence properties in a hibernate.properties file. How do I point the persistence.xml file to the hibernate.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You simply define the Hibernate-specific properties in persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
</properties>
```

You can also put JPA 2 standard properties as listed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging) in the `properties` element as well.

When the application is fired up, Hibernate will read the properties here and be configured accordingly.